# Is it possible to programmatically start playing music on a watchOS 2 device connected to Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

I have a watchOS 2.0 app where I want to be able to start playing music for a user on their device from their iTunes library. I can currently start playing music on the iPhone if I use sendMessage from the WatchConnectivity framework. I am hoping to be able to start playing music from the Apple Watch if the iPhone is not present, but I can't seem to find an API to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so what API's are available?

UPDATE:
I see that I can play audio files from the Apple Watch using WKAudioFileAsset. I am still not able to figure out how to play music that has been synced by the Music app however.